# error installing "rgl" package, version 0.100.19 in anaconda/jupyter-notebook. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I like to install "rgl" package version 0.100.19 (since the other package depends on this version) in anaconda/jupyter notebook environment and received error. 
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted

I tried 
sudo apt-get install xorg 
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev 
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev 
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgl
conda install -c conda-forge xorg-libx11 
conda install -c anaconda mesa
but, they did not help yet.

install.packages("rgl")
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem, my solution was to:

```
$ conda install r-rgl
```

It seems like the conda install goes to the conda R (see this with `which R`), and the way I found to get rgl installed on conda's R version was via conda install.